# Custom TabBar colour iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I want to use custom TabBar colour.

Afetr iOS 5 release I used the following code:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIImage *tabBarBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar.png"];
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:tabBarBG];
[view setBackgroundColor:color];
[color release];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 4.9) {

[self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:view atIndex:1];
}
else {

[self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
}

[view release];
```

In iOS 5 it was OK, but in iOS 5.0.1 it doesn't work.

How can I set TabBar colour in iOS 5.0.1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that trick any more in iOS5 because of the new appearance APIs. You can set properties like backgroundImage and tintColor on tab bars in iOS 5, so just do something like this:

```
if ([self.tabBarController.tabBar respondsToSelect:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)])
{
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = someImage;
}
else
{
    //use the old iOS4 subview hack
}
```